# Multiple before_filter statements for correct_user and admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, before-filter, role-base-authorization

I have a Group resource that I'm trying to set up with proper authorizations.

The authorization logic I'm trying to implement is this:

1. Only group members should be able to view their group.
2. An admin can view *any* group, as well as take other actions.

I'm attempting to do this with the following before_filter statements in the group controller:

```
before_filter :signed_in_user
before_filter :correct_user, only: :show
before_filter :admin_user, only: [:show, :index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Correct_user works as I have verified that only group members can view their group. However, what I want to happen is for the admin :show clause to override this, so that an admin can view any group. Currently that is not working. I'm guessing I have something wrong here with my filter ordering and options.

Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong?

**EDIT**

Adding my method code per Amar's request:

```
private

def correct_user
  # User has to be a member to view
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_path) if @group.members.find_by_member_id(current_user).nil?
end

def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
end
```

Comment: Try admin_user before filter above correct_user  or in show action make conditional for admin user and other

Comment: Thanks Amar. I tried putting the admin_user filter above correct_user but that didn't fix it. I could put the condition in the action but want to see if there's a way to do it with before_filter.

Comment: On further inspection with the way I have it written above the filter is requiring the user to be both and admin AND a correct_user in order to view the group. I want it to be OR

Comment: Can u debug your method using debugger or pry you can get fair idea what is wrong might be you are doing right or can u post code so i can dig into it.

Comment: Appreciate your help, Amar. Just posted the method code above.

Comment: Ok,so when admin login and he is not member in that case it will redirect so for show method you can create following method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the correct_user method or create another method with the following definition, remove show from other filter and add before_filter with new method.

```
def correct_user
   @group = Group.find(params[:id])
   redirect_to(root_path) if @group.members.find_by_member_id(current_user).nil?  && !current_user.admin?
end
```

Comment: Just tested and that works great. I needed to add a "&&" in between the boolean statements.