# Rails before_filter (Correct_user OR Admin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to allow either the correct user or the admin user to delete a model. How do I set this up?

Controller

```
  before_filter :correct_user,    only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter   :admin_user,    only: :destroy
  ...
  private
def signed_in_user
  unless signed_in?
    store_location
    redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in."
  end
end
def correct_user
  if (Event.find(params[:id]).user_id != current_user.id)
    redirect_to events_path, :notice => "You do not own this event"
  end
end
def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
end
```

Currently the user needs to be both the admin and owner of the model. I would like to have an either or permission arrangement.

Comment: then use `||` or `or` instead of `&&` or `and` in your current comparison.

Comment: I'm looking to change the before_filter "only" to something else

Comment: Your question is pretty much a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150098/multiple-before-filter-statements-for-correct-user-and-admin